# lighttpd configuration to proxy/rewrite from one domain to another

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd, mod-proxy

i need to setup proxy/rewrite on lighttpd!

i have server1, which serves via http 2 different web app paths:

```
* http://server1/path1
* http://server1/path2
```

also, i have lighttpd server in front of server1

i want to setup rewriting and/or proxing on lighttpd, so that each of the 2 paths would be served as root path on different domains:

```
* requests to http://server2.com/* are proxied/rewrited to http://server1/path1/*
* requests to http://server3.com/* are proxied/rewrited to http://server1/path2/*
```

important:

- server2.com and server3.com can access server1 *only via http*
- redirects are not the option, users of server2.com & server3.com shouldn't not know that the actual web apps are served from different paths of server1.

Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question isn't about programming or programming tools, so we can't help you here. However, our friends over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) probably can - be sure to search before asking and [read their FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) for help on constructing a good question.

Answer (score 5):

Your need is known by lighttpd developers from several years.

It is answered by a workaround or new feature depending on the version.

**Lighttpd 1.4**

A workaround is explained in the bugtracker : [bug #164](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/164#note-9)

> ```
> $HTTP["url"] =~ "(^/path1/)" {   
>   proxy.server  = ( "" => ("" => ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 81 ))) 
> }
>
> $SERVER["socket"] == ":81" {   
>   url.rewrite-once = ( "^/path1/(.*)$" => "/$1" )   
>   proxy.server  = ( "" => ( "" => ( "host" => "server2.com", "port" => 80 ))) 
> }
> ```

**Lighttpd 1.5**

They added this feature with this command ([official documentation](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModProxyCore)) :

> **proxy-core.rewrite-request** : rewrite request headers or request uri.
>
> ```
> $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/path1" {
>   proxy-co...
>
>   proxy-core.rewrite-request = (
>     "_uri" => ( "^/path1/?(.*)" => "/$1" ),
>     "Host" => ( ".*" => "server2.com" ),
>   )
> }
> ```

Comment: FWIW, it seems that the 1.5 version has been abandoned before reaching the first release.  I guess this means we're stuck with the workaround.

Comment: For v1.4, the solution doesn't work. It redirects but doesn't change the path

Answer (score 0):

Update: lighttpd 1.4.46 (released in 2017) introduced `proxy.header` which can perform limited URL-prefix rewriting. More info at [lighttpd mod_proxy](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModProxy)